# How to use a sum of values for each row using awk

Tags: awk

I have a small txt file:

```
Josh 10
Bill 10
Samanda 30
```

The sum of all nums is 50.
How can I use this sum for dividing values on each row?

```
0.2 # 10/50
0.2 # 10/50
0.6 # 30/50
```

My awk script doesn't work as expected:

```
BEGIN {
sum += $2;
}
{
print $2/sum
}
```

It returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  val[NR]=$2
  sum+=$2
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
    print sum?val[i]/sum:0
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  val[NR]=$2                     ##Creating array val whose index is  current line number and value is 2nd field of current line.
  sum+=$2                        ##Creating sum which has 2nd column value in it which is keep on getting added in it.
}
END{                             ##Starting END block of this code here.
  for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){            ##Starting a for loop from i 1 to till value of count here.
    print sum?val[i]/sum:0       ##Printing val[i]/sum value here if sum is NOT NULL else printing 0 here.
  }
}
' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

`BEGIN` is true before any input file is open which is why your `sum += $2` in your script does nothing but set `sum` to zero.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sum+=$2; next} {print (sum ? $2/sum : "NaN")}' file file
0.2
0.2
0.6
```

The ternary is to protect against dividing by zero if `sum` is zero.